# When to use 'would' properly in a novel

Tags: adverbs, subjunctive-mood

I am a little confused about the usage of 'would' in fiction-writing/translation.

So, here's a very simple example that confuses me.

*"Why did you say that?" she asked.* -- (my version)
*"Why would you say that?" she asked* --(editor's version)

I don't understand the difference.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why would he do this to me?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64472/why-would-he-do-this-to-me)

Comment: This is a **politeness** issue; "Why did you say that?" in many contexts is abrupt, challenging. "Why would you say that?" utilises one of the many usages of the overworked modal 'would'; the meaning is the same as the obvious 'did' version, but this is a greatly hedged variant. Imagine Miss Marple: "Now why would you say that, my dear?" // Probably not the same usage as in 'Why would he do this to me?'

Comment: Thank you! This helps!